# GNU Linux Makefile PHONY target dependencies not working correctly

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to get some dependent install targets to work in my Makefile as follows:

```
.PHONY: install-everything install-part1 install-part2

install-everything: install-part1 install-part2

install-part1:
    $(call part1-function)

install-part2:
    $(call part2-function)
```

This is very similar to that described in the GNU Make manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

I did

```
make install-part1
```

first, then manually (i.e. rm -rf) removed the $(DESTDIR) directory that got created.

Now, every time I try to run any of the targets listed above, I get e.g:

```
make: nothing to be done for 'install-everything'.
```

I get the same answer if I try to force make with the '-B' flag. If I add debug info (make --debug) I get

```
File 'install-everything' does not exist.
Must remake target 'install-everything'.
```

I thought that using the .PHONY directive would fix this problem - can anyone help?

Comment: It could be that your `$(call partX-function)` expand to nothing. If it is the case, all recipes are empty and the message you get is correct: there is nothing to be done. Please show an example of your `partX-function` macros.

Comment: It's just creating some directories and then copying stuff in: 
    define install-part1:
        $(mkdir -p $(1))
        $(cp -r files $(1))
    endef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `partX-function` macros, as you explain in your comment, expand to the empty string. What they **do** when called and how they **expand** are two different things. As a consequence your recipes are all empty and make tells you this with its `nothing to be done` message. It is not smart enough to analyze your macros and discover that they do something. Your use of GNU make and of its `call` function is unconventional. For the example you show, it would be much better to use plain make (unless you have a lot of files to install and performance matters):

```
.PHONY: install-everything install-part1 install-part2

install-everything: install-part1 install-part2

install-part1: $(addprefix $(DIR1)/,$(FILES1))

$(DIR1):
    mkdir -p $@

$(addprefix $(DIR1)/,$(FILES1)): $(DIR1)/%: $(SRCDIR)/% | $(DIR1)
    cp -f $< $@

install-part2:...
```

(assuming make variables `SRCDIR`, `DIR1` and `FILES1` define the source directory, the destination directory for `install-part1` and the list of files to copy for `install-part1`, respectively).

In order to fully understand this example makefile, you will need to understand [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage) and [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

If you have a lot of files to install and performance matters it is better to group the copy (`cp`) and thus reduce the number of shell invocations:

```
install-part1: $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(FILES1)) | $(DIR1)
    for f in $(FILES1); do \
         cp -f $(SRCDIR)/$$f $(DIR1);\
    done
```

or even:

```
install-part1: $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(FILES1)) | $(DIR1)
    cp -f $^ $(DIR1)
```

It is less elegant because all dependencies are not properly declared. And all files will be copied each time you invoke `make install-part1`, even if they are already installed and up-to-date, but it should be much faster than with the other solution.

Last but not least: under GNU/Linux installation frequently uses the `install` utility instead of `cp`...